# Extract main feature of paragraphs using word2vec

Tags: python, word2vec, feature-extraction

I just got a hold of Google's word2vec model and am quite new to the concept. i am trying to extract the main feature of a paragraph using the following method.

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('../../usr/myProject/word2vec/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)

...

for para in paragraph_array:
    para_name = "para_"+ file_name + '{0}'
    sentence_array = d[para_name.format(number_of_paragraphs)] = []

    # Split Paragraph on basis of '.' or ? or !.
    for l in re.split(r"\.|\?|\!", para):
        # Split line into list using space.
        sentence_array.append(l)
        #sentence_array.append(l.split(" "))

     print (model.wv.most_similar(positive=para, topn = 1))
```

But am getting the following error where it says that the paragraph checked is not a word in the vocabulary.

> KeyError: 'word \'The Republic of Ghana is a country in West Africa. It borders Côte d\'Ivoire (also known as Ivory Coast) to the west, Burkina Faso to the north, Togo to the east, and the Gulf of Guinea to the south. The word "Ghana" means "Warrior King", Jackson, John G. Introduction to African Civilizations, 2001. Page 201.  and was the source of the name "Guinea" (via French Guinoye) used to refer to the West African coast (as in Gulf of Guinea).\' not in vocabulary'

Now I am aware that the `most_similar()` function expects a single array. But I would like to know how this can be translated to extract one main feature or word that displays the  main concept of the paragraph using the word2vec model.

**Modified**

I modified the above code to pass the word_array into the `most_similar()` method and I' getting the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/PycharmProjects/ChatbotWord2Vec/new_approach.py", line 108, in 
>       print(model.wv.most_similar(positive=word_array, topn=1))
>     File "/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/usr/myProject/my_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 361, in most_similar
>       for word, weight in positive + negative:
>   ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

**Modified Implementation**

```
for sentence in sentence_array:
    if sentence:
        for w in re.split(r"\.|\?|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\-",   sentence):
            split_word = w.split(" ")
            if split_word:
                word_array.append(split_word)
print(model.wv.most_similar(positive=word_array, topn=1))
```

Any suggestions in this regard are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked the entire code adding checkpoints to avoid the storage of empty strings to objects at each level starting from paragraphs, sentences down to words.

**Working Version**

```
for file_name in files:
    file_identifier = file_name
    file_array = file_dictionary[file_identifier] =[]
    #file_array = file_dictionary[file_name.format((file_count))] = []
    file_path = directory_path+'/'+file_name

    with open(file_path) as f:
        #Level 2 Intents : Each file's main intent (One for each file)
        first_line = f.readline()
        print ()
        print("Level 2 Intent for ", c, " : ", first_line)

        #Level 3 Intents : Each paragraph's main intent (one for each para)

        paragraph_count = 0

        data = f.read()
        splat = data.split("\n")
        paragraph_array = []

        for number, paragraph in enumerate(splat, 1):
            paragraph_identifier = file_name + "_paragraph_" + str(paragraph_count)
            #print(paragraph_identifier)
            paragraph_array = paragraph_dictionary[paragraph_identifier.format(paragraph_count)] = []
            if paragraph :
                paragraph_array.append(paragraph)
            paragraph_count += 1
            if len(paragraph_array) >0 :
                file_array.append(paragraph_array)

            # Level 4 Intents : Each sentence's main intent (one for each sentence)

            sentence_count = 0
            sentence_array = []

            for sentence in paragraph_array:
                for line in re.split(r"\.|\?|\!", sentence):
                    sentence_identifier = paragraph_identifier + "_sentence_" + str(sentence_count)
                    sentence_array = sentence_dictionary[sentence_identifier.format(sentence_count)] = []
                    if line :
                        sentence_array.append(line)
                        sentence_count += 1

                    # Level 5 Intents : Each word with a certain level of prominance (one for each prominant word)

                    word_count = 0
                    word_array = []

                    for words in sentence_array:
                        for word in re.split(r" ", words):
                            word_identifier = sentence_identifier + "_word_" + str(word_count)
                            word_array = word_dictionary[word_identifier.format(word_count)] = []

                            if word :
                                word_array.append(word)
                                word_count += 1
```

**Code to access dictionary items**

```
#Accessing any paragraph array can be done as follows
print (paragraph_dictionary['S08_set4_a5.txt.clean_paragraph_4'])

#Accessing any sentence corresponding to a paragraph
print (sentence_dictionary['S08_set4_a5.txt.clean_paragraph_4_sentence_1'])

#Accessing any word corresponding to a sentence
print (word_dictionary['S08_set4_a5.txt.clean_paragraph_4_sentence_1_word_3'])
```

**Output**

```
['Celsius was born in Uppsala in Sweden. He was professor of astronomy at Uppsala University from 1730 to 1744, but traveled from 1732 to 1735 visiting notable observatories in Germany, Italy and France.']
[' He was professor of astronomy at Uppsala University from 1730 to 1744, but traveled from 1732 to 1735 visiting notable observatories in Germany, Italy and France']
['of']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is indicating that you are looking up an entire string (`'The Republic of Ghana is a country in West Africa. It borders Côte d\'Ivoire (also known as Ivory Coast) to the west, Burkina Faso to the north, Togo to the east, and the Gulf of Guinea to the south. The word "Ghana" means "Warrior King", Jackson, John G. Introduction to African Civilizations, 2001. Page 201. and was the source of the name "Guinea" (via French Guinoye) used to refer to the West African coast (as in Gulf of Guinea).'`) as if it were one word, and that word isn't present.

The `most_similar()` method can take a list of positive examples, but you'd have to tokenize that string into words that are likely to be inside the set of word-vectors. (That'd likely involve breaking on both whitespace and punctuation to match whatever Google did to prepare that word-vector set.)

In that case, `most_similar()` will average all given words' vectors together, and return the other words closes to that average.

Whether that actually captures the 'main concept' of a text is unclear. While word-vectors may prove useful in identifying a text's concepts, that's not their main or only function, and it's not automatic. You might want to filter the set of words down to those that are unique in some other way – such as less-common overall, or otherwise impactful in some corpus-dependent measure (like TF/IDF).

Comment: Thanks for this elucidation. So in the case of passing a list of positive examples to the `most_similar()` method, is it viable to use a `list` object where each and every word in the paragraph is a list item and then pass that `list` to the `most_similar()` method?

Comment: Yes, though you might additionally want to discard words not known to the model, to avoid triggering a `KeyError` on words not present.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: I modified my code as you've suggested and am running into another error. I have added the modified code and error to the above question. Your advice in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should show what `word_array` value is triggering the error.

Comment: In reworking the entire code, I added checkpoints to avoid the storage of empty strings to objects starting from paragraphs, sentences down to words. Now I seem to be getting the desired results. I have added the working version's code as an answer herewith. Thanks a million for your pointers. They were quite helpful.